# Merge element of nested List in unique list c#

Tags: c#, list

I have a nested List as in the example:

```
List<List<int>> myList = new List<List<int>>();
myList.Add(new List<int> { 2, 7, 3 });
myList.Add(new List<int> { 4, 6});
myList.Add(new List<int> { 2, 5, 1 });
myList.Add(new List<int> { 7, 0, 2 });
myList.Add(new List<int> { 4, 9 });
```

I want to merge  all the lists having at least an element in common so that the output will be a `List<List<int>>` with elements:

```
List<int> 2, 7, 3, 5, 1, 0
List<int> 4,6,9
```

Thank you

Comment: You can use Linq's Intersect to check if two lists contain common elements.

Comment: tricky problem, harder than it looks like, IMHO

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`HashSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) for a solution, though I am sure efficiency can be improved:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<List<int>> myList = new List<List<int>>();
    myList.Add(new List<int> { 2, 7, 3 });
    myList.Add(new List<int> { 4, 6});
    myList.Add(new List<int> { 2, 5, 1 });
    myList.Add(new List<int> { 7, 0, 2 });
    myList.Add(new List<int> { 4, 9 });
    var result = FindCommonSets(myList);
}

static List<HashSet<T>> FindCommonSets<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> data)
{
    List<HashSet<T>> sets = new List<HashSet<T>>();
    bool anyModified = false;
    foreach (var list in data)
    {
        //find a set which already overlaps this list.
        var set = sets.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Overlaps(list));
        if (set != null)
        {
            //if we find one, dump all the elements of this list into the set.
            set.UnionWith(list);
            anyModified = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //if not, add a new set based on this list.
            sets.Add(new HashSet<T>(list));
        }
    }
    if (anyModified)
    {
        //run the whole thing again with the new data if anything was changed in this iteration.
        return FindCommonSets(sets);
    }
    return sets;
}
```

edit: Changed to a recursive implementation following the issues brought up in the comments.

Comment: Tricky problem. Your solution works for the input example in OP, but it doesn't work for : `{ 2, 7, 3 }, { 4, 6 }, { 5, 1 }, { 7, 0, 2 }, { 4, 9 },  { 2, 5 }` for instance. In this case the last {2, 5} should cause two of the already existing sets to be merged in one, which isn't the case with your code.

Comment: I think the fix will be to repeat the merge using the new sets, until no sets are found that need merging.